# Trigger Sound before going to new page

Tags: javascript, html

I have this proyect to deliver to my school where I need to make a page, I was thinking of making a portfolio similar to a game but I want the person to click a a custom button a made and before it redirects it to the new page, it can make a custom sound for it.

```
    <header headerIndex>
  <audio id="selectaudio" preload="auto">
    <source  src="./audio/selectsound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
  <a href="./pages/welcome.html" class="rpgui-button beginButton" id="playAudio">Lets Begin!</a>
    </header>
```

So this is my code here, nothing special at all. How can I make it do the audio sound before moving onto the new page called "welcome.html".

If there is any javascript needed, I can add it as I will try to understand what it does haha. Thank you!

Comment: Do not mark the question "Solved" in the title -- instead, use the green check mark to accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a little time for the sound to be played before you redirect to another page.

This is how I would do it (Jquery needed):

```
<a onClick="return makeSound('www.example.cmo');" href="#">Click on me!</div>
```

And JS

```
function makeSound(url) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
    var audio = new Audio('https://freetestdata.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Free_Test_Data_500KB_WAV.wav');
    audio.play();
  
  setTimeout(function() {
     window.location.href = url;
}, 1000);
}
```

https://codepen.io/yortem/pen/gOzbYLb

Comment: Sorry, is there any additional steps to add Jquery to my html? I've never used it as like I said, I have never used javascript before haha.

Comment: You ned to add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>` before the code I just gave you. and also wrap that code inside `<script> .... </script>`.

The code should be placed at the bottom, before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let audio = document.getElementById("selectAudio");
function bell() {
   audio.play();
}     
let playAudio = document.getElementById("playAudio").onclick = bell();
```

I think this should help, I am also new with JavaScript

Comment: on var audio = new audio, should i put where the audio is located or how will it recognize the audio i have?

Comment: @SirHalconsito since your audio file is in the same file directory your html or javascript file is in, just like in your html audio tag. new Audio = (/audio/selectsound.mp3)

Comment: unfortunately it still does not make any sound when clicked the button :(

Comment: @SirHalconsito aww, sorry about that. Let me try to find a solution